# How to UPDATE a table entry based on the most recent entry with the same id in another table?

Tags: sql-update

Apologies if I am asking the obvious, but as a beginner, the obvious is not always that obvious.

In an employee database, I am maintaining a table of positions the employee has had during his employment with the company. For the sake of simplicity, I will keep the code as short as possible.

I have a temporary table based on the position table.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp AS SELECT * FROM saireco.position LIMIT 0;
```

The temporary table gets the latest information from the source system. I remove unwanted entries from the temp table. Next, I update the temporary table if the EmployeeStatusCode in the temporary table is different from the EmployeeStatusCode in the position table (the SET command here does not have any particular meaning).

```sql
UPDATE tmp t
  SET "PositionCreationDate" = '2022-05-16'
FROM saireco."position" p
WHERE (t."EmployeeID" = p."EmployeeID"
   AND t."EmploymentStatusCode" != p."EmploymentStatusCode")
;
```

The above code is flawed because the position table can contain multiple entries for the same employee (the temporary table tmp will only contain a maximum of one entry per employee). I have come up with the following code which uses the latest sequence id "PositionID".

```sql
UPDATE tmp t
  SET "PositionCreationDate" = '2022-05-16'
FROM saireco."position" p
WHERE (t."EmployeeID" = p."EmployeeID"
   AND t."EmploymentStatusCode" != p."EmploymentStatusCode")
   AND p."PositionID" IN (SELECT MAX(pp."PositionID") FROM saireco."position" pp WHERE pp."EmployeeID" = t."EmployeeID")
;
```

My questions are twofold. Is this the correct way to achieve what I would like to achieve, e.g. update the temporary table if the most recent entry for the "EmployeeID" has changed; note the "PositionID" is a sequence which automatically gets incremented when a new entry is added to the table)? Secondly, because I already ensure the "EmployeeID" is equal here `SELECT MAX(pp."PositionID") FROM saireco."position" pp WHERE pp."EmployeeID" = t."EmployeeID"`, does it mean I can get rid of the first condition `t."EmployeeID" = p."EmployeeID"`, resulting in the following code?

```sql
UPDATE tmp t
  SET "PositionCreationDate" = '2022-05-16'
FROM saireco."position" p
WHERE (t."EmploymentStatusCode" != p."EmploymentStatusCode")
   AND p."PositionID" IN (SELECT MAX(pp."PositionID") FROM saireco."position" pp WHERE pp."EmployeeID" = t."EmployeeID")
;
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.